# How to get all indexes which had a particular value in last row of a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For a sample DataFrame like,

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=6, freq='15T')
>>> data = ['ON_PEAK', 'OFF_PEAK', 'ON_PEAK', 'ON_PEAK', 'OFF_PEAK', 'OFF_PEAK']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=['tou'])
>>> df
                          tou
2018-01-01 00:00:00   ON PEAK
2018-01-01 00:15:00  OFF PEAK
2018-01-01 00:30:00   ON PEAK
2018-01-01 00:45:00   ON PEAK
2018-01-01 01:00:00  OFF PEAK
2018-01-01 01:15:00  OFF PEAK
```

How to get all indexes for which `tou` value is not `ON_PEAK` but of row before them is `ON_PEAK`, i.e. the output would be:

```
['2018-01-01 00:15:00', '2018-01-01 01:00:00']
```

Or, if it's easier to get all rows with `ON_PEAK` and the first row next to them, i.e

```
['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:15:00', '2018-01-01 00:30:00', '2018-01-01 00:45:00', '2018-01-01 01:00:00']
```

Comment: Why don't I see `2018-01-01 00:45:00` in the output? The `tou` before that is `ON PEAK`.

Comment: Good point. I framed the question better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find rows where `tou` is not `ON_PEAK` and the previous `tou` found using [pandas.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) is `ON_PEAK`. Note that positive values in `shift` give nth previous values and negative values gives nth next value in the dataframe.

```
df.loc[(df['tou']!='ON_PEAK') & (df['tou'].shift(1)=='ON_PEAK')]
```

Output:

```
                       tou
2018-01-01 00:15:00 OFF_PEAK
2018-01-01 01:00:00 OFF_PEAK
```

Comment: Great. So even the second part can be done similarly, `df.loc[(df['tou']=='ON_PEAK') | (df['tou'].shift(1)=='ON_PEAK')]`

Comment: @DEEPAKSURANA, not sure, I understand second part. May be you can clarify and ask another question for it? SO needs to have one question-answer pair per post. If you want a pair of rows with `ON_PEAK` your code with `&` would work.

Comment: actually I tried and it will work. The second part was to select rows next to `ON_PEAK` as well as all `ON_PEAK`.

Comment: @DEEPAKSURANA, great. Happy coding.